# CSS - Floating Two Divs Next To Eachother, Instead They Go Underneath Eachother

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to position two divs next to eachother, and keeping the mobile visitors in mind.

The problem: Instead of floating next to eachother, when there's a good amount of text used in the div, it goes underneath.

Here's an example:

```css
.codeblock {
     width:500px;
}
.left{
     float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="codeblock">
     <img src="https://placehold.it/307x322" class="left" style="width:125px">
     <div class="left">
           <h3>Some title</h3>
           <p>Some text with a long explanation of how buildings don't make the Earth any heavier because all the materials were already on it.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Why is this happening? Is there a solution, without using fixed values (excluding the image style width)?

Comment: is the image always the same width?

Comment: css floats are for content flow, not for 'positioning' stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float only the image

```css
.codeblock {
     width:500px;
}
.left{
     float: left;
     margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="codeblock">
     <img src="https://placehold.it/307x322" class="left" style="width:125px">
     <div >
           <h3>Some title</h3>
           <p>Some text with a long explanation of how buildings don't make the Earth any heavier because all the materials were already on it.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember that you have to clear floats after content, or set `.codeblock`'s `overflow` property to `hidden`

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use flexbox instead of float. It will be a little bit more work, but it is a new feature and always good to try new things.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**UPDATE**

Like this: no class. You inform the main class that it is flexbox and its son will have a padding do separate them.

```css
.codeblock {
  display: flex;
  width:500px;
}
.codeblock > * {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="codeblock">
     <img src="https://placehold.it/307x322">
     <div >
           <h3>Some title</h3>
           <p>Some text with a long explanation of how buildings don't make the Earth any heavier because all the materials were already on it.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agreed. What part of the page are you referring to?

Comment: @AppelFlap I've update the comment with the flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Considering mobile users I would do this that way with `flex-wrap` and min values for content

```css
.codeblock {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-width:500px;
}

.codeblock>img {
  flex: 0 0 125px;
  width: 125px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.codeblock>div {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="codeblock">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/307x322">
  <div>
    <h3>Some title</h3>
    <p>Some text with a long explanation of how buildings don't make the Earth any heavier because all the materials were already on it.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```